# Global KeyBoard Hook and device infos

Tags: keyboard, window, hook

i have this Working example in C++ of a keyboard hook

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

HHOOK keyboardHook{ NULL };


LRESULT CALLBACK MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc(const int nCode, const WPARAM wParam, const LPARAM lParam)
{

    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kb = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

    switch (wParam)
    {

    case WM_KEYUP:
        std::cout << "KeyUp event : " << kb->vkCode   << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc, NULL, 0);
    if (keyboardHook == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Keyboard hook failed!" << std::endl;
    }


    while (GetMessage(NULL, NULL, 0, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

i want  to this to read data from an usb rfid card reader that act like a keyboard .

the main problem is how to differentiate the keys that come from the reader and that come from the real keyboard .

i have tested the **dwExtraInfo** parameter of KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT  but gave me 0 in both cases (keyboard/card reader)

any help/idea/suggestion is welcome

thanks .

Comment: Edit: i have found this sample that seems to adress the issue i am facing , unfortunally after testing i got another problem : i have some random keys lost , so instead of having the 10 card characters, i get sometimes and randomely 8 or 9 . any idea on what's going on ? and waht can cause this ? ps i am on windows 8.1 64 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

Comment: aslo have found this library wich look really promissing but i can't figure out how to use it for my purpose http://www.oblita.com/interception.html